# what is wrong with this? trying to play a sound when i hover with my curser, but works only when i click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hover

So it works when I clicked, but I cannot figure out how to make it work on hover?

**HTML** Code

```
<body>

<audio autoplay id="HAT2" >
<source src="OOOOO_1_HAT.mp3" >
Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

<ul>
<a id="play_me" href="brower_visualizasion.html" ><li>PLAY ME</li></a>

</ul>

</body>
```

And for the interaction i have used the jQuery and I tried with other functions than `.mouseenter` like .on(`mouseover`).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  var audio = $("#HAT2")[0];
  console.log(audio);
  $("#play_me.play").mouseenter(function() {
  audio.play();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: try remove `.play` from `"#play_me.play"` since you have no class with play in the a link

Answer (score 1):

You have no class with `play` so remove that from your mouseEnter function

`$("#play_me.play").mouseenter(function() {` should be `$("#play_me").mouseenter(function() {`

**Demo**

```js
var audio = $("#HAT2")[0];
console.log(audio);
$("#play_me").mouseenter(function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<audio autoplay id="HAT2">
<source src="https://www.mfiles.co.uk/mp3-downloads/mozart-horn-concerto4-3-rondo.mp3" >
Your browser isn't invited for super fun audio time.
</audio>

<ul>
  <a id="play_me" href="brower_visualizasion.html">
    <li>PLAY ME</li>
  </a>

</ul>
```

Comment: so i deleted the .play but it still wont work when i hover over it, only when i click it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps you. use hover function instead of Mouseenter like

```
 $("#play_me.play").hover(function()
```